# Writing 100k deletes SSJS in DE and applied filter to column SCD_FLG and value D. Below code got failed in automation. Any leads will be appreciated

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, automationstudio

```js
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var config = {
    name: "91D16891-FEEC-4C5C-A6E9-729D7E612B5A",
    cols: ["OFFER_DK"],
    filter: {
        Property: "SCD_FLG",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "D"
    }
}

retrieveRecords(config);

function retrieveRecords(config) {

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    var moreData = true,
        reqID = data = null;

    while (moreData) {

        moreData = false;

        if (reqID == null) {
            data = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + config.name + "]", config.cols, config.filter);
        } else {
            data = prox.getNextBatch("DataExtensionObject[" + config.name + "]", reqID);
        }

        if (data != null) {
            moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
            reqID = data.RequestID;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                var result_list = data.Results[i].Properties;
                
                for (k in result_list) {
                    var key = result_list[k].Name;
                    var val = result_list[k].Value
                    if (key.indexOf("_") != 0) 
                    {
                        if(key=="OFFER_DK")
                        {
                            var rowDelete = prox.deleteBatch('r_gmdr_team_offer_training',['OFFER_DK'],[val]);
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: First try wrapping your code in ‘try… catch’ blocks that will allow to display the error using ‘Write(Stringify(error))’. Then go run this code on a cloud page to see the error output. Paste the error here if the extended information will not be enough for you to find what’s causing the error to occurr

Comment: Try also reducing the number of records being processed to see if it is potentially timing out in the 30 minute script limit.

Comment: @Gortonington thank you for the response. It is not showing a time-out error but a script.